# Use mathematical induction to prove that $ \frac{(2n)!}{(2^n)} $ is a natural number for all n $\ge $ 0.

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, induction, divisibility

$ \frac{(2n)!}{(2^n)} $ is a natural number for all n $ \ge $ 0.

Base case: n = 1

$ \frac{(2(1))!}{(2^{1})} $ = $ \frac{2*1}{2} $ =  1

My understanding is that there could be a way to figure out the induction step by proving that $ 2^n $ divides (2n)! for all n $ \ge $ 0. However, I was also looking at how for some number k, where n + 1 = k + 1, then

$ \frac{(2(k+1))!}{(2^{k+1})} $ = $ \frac{(2k+2))!}{(2^{k+1})} $.

I just don't know if I should take this approach or choose to do something with mod. Any thoughts or help? Thank you.

Comment: Try using the fact that $(2k+2)!=(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!$

Comment: Note $\frac{(2k+2)!}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{2k!}{2^k}*\frac{(2k + 1)(2k + 2)}{2} = N*\frac{(2k + 1)(2k + 2)}{2}$ for some Natural number $N$.

Comment: Thoughts after seeing the problem: Why would **anyone** do this with induction, while we have $2, 4, 6\cdots, 2n$ in $(2n)!$ already...

Comment: This must be a textbook drill on induction, since a direct proof is actually simpler (there are $n$ even numbers between $1$ and $2n$, qed)

Comment: Writing out $\frac{(2n)!}{2^k}=\frac{(1*3*.....*2n-1)*(2*......*2n)}{2^n} = \frac{(1*3*....*2n-1)*2^n*(n!)}{2^n} = (1*3*...*2n-1)n! \in \mathbb N$ may be easier and obvious for us but I can see it being difficult for a student to figure out how to properly express or why a student may not think of it.  When in doubt, a proof by induction can usually be forced.  Although I personally prefer direct proofs as the tell me *why* something is true and not just that it's a lucky (infinite) string of good fortune.

Answer (score 1):

Let it be true for $n=k$, so let $a_k=\frac{(2k)!}{2^{k}}$.
Let $n=k+1$: $a_{k+1}=\frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{(2k)!}{2^{k}}\cdot\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{2}=a_k(2k+1)(k+1)$.
If $a_k$ is an integer then $a_{k+1}$ is one too.

Answer (score 0):

So you did it right for the base step. Now let's assume that it is true for n=k. That is, $$\frac{(2k)!}{2^{k}}$$
Now we need to show that assumption is also true for $n=k+1$.
That is, we need to show that $$A=\frac{(2(k+1)!}{2^{k+1}}\in \mathbb{N}.$$ 
But $A$ is the same as $$\frac{((2k)!)(2k+1)(2k+2)}{2^k2}.$$
By the assumption we made, $\frac{(2k)!}{2^{k}} \in \mathbb{N}$. The rest part of $A$, which is $$\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{2}$$ is also belongs to a set of natural numbers, since two numbers in the numerator are consecutive ones, and one of them has to be divisible by 2. Here we finish=)

Answer (score 0):

The trick to induction is to somehow express the $k+1$ value in terms of the $k$ value and see what happens when we apply the proposition to the $k$ case.

So we want $\frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{(2k + 2)!}{2^{k+1}} = something-to-do-with(\frac{(2k)!}{2^k})$.

Factoring out $\frac{(2k)!}{2^k}$ it's easy to see:

$\frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{(2k + 2)!}{2^{k+1}} =\frac{(2k)!}{2^k}*\frac{(2k + 1)(2k+2)}{2} = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k}*(2k+1)(k+1)$.

So now.... we see where the chips fall when we apply the proposition for $k$.

$\frac{(2k)!}{2^k} = N \in \mathbb N$

So $\frac{(2(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}} =  \frac{(2k)!}{2^k}*(2k+1)(k+1) = N(2k+1)(k+1) \in \mathbb N$.